# How to calculate temperature resistance for Ni-RTD

Tags: rtd

I would like to build a circuit to read the signal from a thermopile temperature sensor which has build-in RTD temperature sensor for cold-junction compensation. The datasheet of the sensor is [here](http://lusosat.org/hardware/200612916515751780.pdf). I need to know the resistance value of the built-in Ni-RTD at some particular temperature to build the circuit. I search the web to check how can I calculate the resistance value but all I could find is the formula for a platinum RTD. Could you guide me how to calculate the resistance value for a Ni-RTD?

Thank you very much.

[UPDATE]

I have used the Temperature Coeficient Resistance (TCR) to calculate the resistance at temperature T: *Rt = R0*[1+(TCR)*T]*
However as I know the real temperature-resistance curve is not linear, is there a similar formula like the Callendar-Van Dusen equation to fix the curve?

Answer (score 1):

Updated with a better calculator

Use an online calculator like [this](http://www.mod-tronic.com/Minco_SensorCalc.html) with R = 1000 ohm, there is a NI-RTD with a temperature coefficient of 0.00618 that I think it is an approximation of the 0.006178 that you have, it should be the same material.

If you need a polynomial approximation use together with [this tool](https://www.dcode.fr/lagrange-interpolating-polynomial)

For samples at 0, 40, 80, 120 degrees the formula is:
R = 1000(1 + 0.00549577t + 0.000006156t^2 + 0.000000006732t^3)

Or use the values from the table to find A, B and C in the CALLENDAR-VAN DUSEN formula.

Choose the sample points close to your interest area

It's true that there are errors of a few percents with the linearized formula, the maximum error is somewhere around 40 degrees.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these formulas:

[image]

Which are derived from [this](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=NI1000SOT&DocType=DS&DocLang=English) similar sensor datasheet.

It's fairly close to linear for this particular purpose, especially over the relatively narrow temperature range in which the sensor would likely operate.